# IE7 opacity problem by Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the following website we have a dropdown menu with rollover effact.
this function perfactly but in IE7 the opacity is not working correctly.

Any tip?

http://webentwicklungsserver.ch/2011-08-25/index.php

As both white and Gray text will be displayed and is difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Internet Explorer can't render transparent graphics and opacity effects well. There is no real solution against that problem by just changing CSS or javascript values. It's about the rendering engine of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

CSS style opacity is not supported in IE8 or older. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For IE you can use filter:Alpha http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also read about opacity and compatibility with IE in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity